# Quick way to enable only the web searches I want in Quicksilver

Tags: quicksilver

Quicksilver has hundreds of different web searches available, but I only want to use a few of them.

I can manually deselect the ones I don't want by navigating to

```
Modules -> Web Searches -> Contents
```

and unchecking the boxes one at a time, but this is extremely tedious. I don't seem to be able to select multiple entries.

Is there a faster way to choose just the web searches I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Quicksilver/PlugIns/Web Search Module.qsplugin
```

Right click and "Show Package Contents".

Then open Contents/Info.plist and go to:

```
QSPresetAdditions > Item 0 > Settings > path
```

and delete the:

```
http://docs.blacktree.com/doku.php?id=quicksilver:web_search_list
```

Restart Quicksilver and your list will be empty.

Then you may manually add your own.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Web Search plug-in from http://qsapp.com/plugins/ has newer lists that don’t rely on Blacktree. You should install it.

And if you don’t want to use the defaults (I don’t), just go into Preferences → Catalog → Plugins and uncheck them. No need to go digging into bundles and hacking at their property lists.

From there, you can add your own using the method if your choice. (Manually, bookmarks, OmniWeb search shortcuts, etc.)

Changes you make inside the plug-in’s bundle will be destroyed on every upgrade. Use the catalog preferences to ensure your search list stays around.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on nuc's answer...

The default search list is at http://docs.blacktree.com/doku.php?id=quicksilver:web_search_list, which redirects to http://querymap.appspot.com/quicksilver-list. This contains a list of search engines, in this format:

```
<div class=QSWebSearchContentStart></div>
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=***">Google Seach</a>
<a href="http://duckduckgo.com/?q=***">DuckDuckGo search</a>
...
<div class=QSWebSearchContentEnd></div>
```

To create your own custom list, create a web page with the desired search engines, and then point Quicksilver to your URL as nuc mentioned:

Open: 
`~/Library/Application Support/Quicksilver/PlugIns/Web Search Module.qsplugin/Contents/Info.plist`

and modify: `QSPresetAdditions > Item 0 > Settings > path`

Note that http://querymap.appspot.com has a list of search engine URLs.